# It's not gettin login in?

Tags: php

I have wrote conditons that is the password and username matches, it gets log in according to the conditions. But As I am new to PHP, I dont know why it is not getting logged in.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include('connect.php');

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
while($query4=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
extract($query4);
$ul=$userlevel;

if ($ul=='A')
{
$_SESSION["username"]=$myusername;
$_SESSION["password"]=$mypassword;
header("location:projectmanager_main.php");
}
else if ($ul=='B')
{
$_SESSION["username"]=$myusername;
$_SESSION["password"]=$mypassword;
header("location:teamlead_main.php");
}
else if ($ul=='C')
{
$_SESSION["username"]=$myusername;
$_SESSION["password"]=$mypassword;
header("location:employees.php");
}
else 
{
$_SESSION["username"]=$myusername;
$_SESSION["password"]=$mypassword;
header("location:admin_main.html");
}

}

}

else
{
echo "<p align='center'>"."<font color='red'>"."Wrong Username or Password. Please Try Again"."</font>"."</p>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all if you are new to PHP, try using `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of  `mysql` extension.

Comment: "As a new to house building could please someone build a house for me for free?" Try to quote any building company with such a proposal.

Comment: Try placing the PHP code on top of the HTML code as opposed to below. session_start() should not work there.. session_start sends cookies to the browser. Cookies are sent before HTML/CSS or any content is sent. session_start() and other header-related features in PHP must be used before the headers are sent. Using "echo" or outputting anything (such as HTML) will send the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `header()` must be called before printing any content of the page.

Your should reorganize your code to something like this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Try to log in the user and redirect with header if successful
}
?>
<html>
<!-- display the login page -->
    <?php
    // if user has not been redirected
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo "login failed";}
    ?>
    <!-- display login form -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so I'll go with an answer *(although, I think this is more appropriate as a comment)*.

For everyone to further assess your problem, you must first do the following:

- Provide an error message. Whatever level it is, it's a good lead to start with.
- If you have any `require()`, `require_once()`, `include()`, `include_once()` on the page, you must show that too.
- Provide any result data you already have. Like in your code, the `$query4=mysql_fetch_array($result)`, what is the value of `$query4`? So we can see, if you are extracting and comparing the right values on the if-else below it.

As I cannot provide an exact answer to your question, by providing *at least* one mentioned above, we can further break down the issue.

Comment: This would serve better as a comment, but I voted as if it were a comment since you're not allowed to comment right now.. :/

Comment: Thanks. By your upvote, I can accumulate reputation to unlock commenting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>

--your table in html here--

<?php 
} else {
include('connect.php');
$myusername= mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username'])); 
$mypassword= mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['password'])); 
$num = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username='$myusername'   AND password='$mypassword'"));
if ($num >= 1) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'true';
header('Location:admin_home.html');
} else {
?>

-- table with error in html here --

<?php
}
}
?>
```